# Exception thrown when deserializing json with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following class

```
public class Airport
{
    [MaxLength(75)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool NotInUse { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(2)]
    public string Iso { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(3)]
    public string Iata { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(4)]
    public string Icao { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following json file - Not all properties are within the json

```
    {
  "Airports":{
  [
    {
       "Name": "Belfast International",
       "City": "Belfast",
       "Country": "United Kingdom",
       "Iso": "GB",
       "Iata": "BFS"
     },
     {
       "Name": "City of Derry",
       "City": "Derry",
       "Country": "United Kingdom",
       "Iso": "GB",
       "Iata": "LDY"

     }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to deserialise the json with this method

```
public IList<Airport> ReadAirportsFromJson()
{
    if (File.Exists(AirportJsonFilename))
    {
        string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(AirportJsonFilename);
        var airports = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Airport>>(fileContents);
        return airports;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I get the following exception

[image: Screenshot]

I am unsure how to progress this and resolve the issue.

Comment: The JSON you listed isn't entirely valid. You can validate it and see the errors with tools like [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/). But, it appears to either have an extra object, `{...}`, if `"Airports"` is supposed to be an array or is missing a key to go with the combined object and array.

Comment: Where are you getting the JSON from? Can you change it? You can *nearly* get it to work by creating a class with a `List<Airports> Airports` property, but even so the value is an object directly containing an array, which I don't *think* is valid JSON.

Comment: the JSON is not valid, indeed ! you can check it by yourself putting the json in [http://json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com)

Comment: The json is something that I have created.  What I am trying to do is use hard coded json file to create some default data for my application, some data to get things started

Comment: @JDibble can you change the json format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json is not valid, I'd suggest changing it to something like this

```
{
  "Airports":
  [
    {
       "Name": "Belfast International",
       "City": "Belfast",
       "Country": "United Kingdom",
       "Iso": "GB",
       "Iata": "BFS"
     },
     {
       "Name": "City of Derry",
       "City": "Derry",
       "Country": "United Kingdom",
       "Iso": "GB",
       "Iata": "LDY"

     }
    ]
}
```

and create a wrapper class

```
public class AirportsWrapper
{
    public List<Airport> Airports { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize the json into `AirportsWrapper` and return the `Airports` property

```
public IList<Airport> ReadAirportsFromJson()
{
    if (File.Exists(AirportJsonFilename))
    {
        string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(AirportJsonFilename);
        var airportsWrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AirportsWrapper>(fileContents);
        if (airportsWrapper != null)
        {
            return airportsWrapper.Airports;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NQ8JfQ

Answer (score 0):

When passing it in like you do there, you're trying to deserialize the entire file into a list of airports. If the entire file is something else that also happens to contain a list of airports, this won't work. You either have to get just the parts of the JSON which is actually the list of airports, or you have to make a class/classes to represent the entire JSON file and deserialize into that. From there on, you can just go to `yourObject.Airports`.